# how to read memory bytes one by one in hex(so without any format) with printf()

Tags: c, hex

I'm interested to read one byte of memory in C.Im using netbeans on ubuntu and below is my code to read just one byte(not the whole value of a). but nothing is printed out on the screen.

```
main()
{
int a[1]={3};
//printf(%d",a[0]); //line 2
printf("\x07",a[0]); //line 3
}
```

in my idea, the memory in address with label a is composed of:

- 0x0004 03
- 0x0008 00
- 0x000c 00
- 0x000f 00

printf() statement in line 2 indicates that go to the address 0x???4 and :

1. read 4 bytes (because of d character)
2. Represent these 4 bytes as a number meaning that multiply them by power of 2 (because of d character)

printf() statement in line 3  use **\**  (and not  %) and bits from 0 to 7 (1 byte). so it indicates that, go address 0x0004 and:

1. List item
2. read 1 byte (because of 07 characters)
   2-Do nothing except that show each 4-bit as a hex value

so the code should print out what the first byte in 0x0004 which is 03. but it does not. any clue?

Thanks in advance

Please don't just correct my syntax. Do you think my hypotheses are correct regarding formatters in printf?

Comment: `printf("\x07",a[0]);` will print the literal number hex `07` and ignore the `a[0]` since you don't have any numeric formatters in your format strings (that start with `%`).

Comment: when i look at the memory using a debugger, i don't format my bits.in the above case, i don't want to format them neither (or at most, i want to see them in binary format or hex format without any number representation.

Comment: The `\xHH` syntax is merely a way of expressing literal numbers in hexadecimal within a C program and is not a syntax used to help with the output of values in any particular format.

Comment: Hexadecimal *is* a format.  Debuggers often use that format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a pointer to address the individual bytes of `a` and change your [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) to use the `%x` format specifier, e.g.:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 3;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&a;
    int i;

    printf("a =");
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a); ++i)
    {
        printf(" %02x", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On a little endian machine with 32 bit ints this should produce the following output:

```
a = 03 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
    int a = 3; // you can use any type you need.
    size_t size = sizeof(a);
    char *phead = malloc(size);
    memcpy(phead,&a,size);
    size_t i;
    char *p = phead;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%02x  ",*p++);
    free( phead); 
}
```

Comment: `char p = phead;` should be `char *p = phead;`. Also `main` needs to return `int`.

Answer (score -1):

printf has a hex formatter.  It is "%x"...

```
$ man 3 printf
```

Same as above, but one that will work with 64 bit integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void) {
    int64_t i, asz, a = 3;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)&a;

    printf("a = 0x");

    for (i = 0, asz = sizeof(a); i < asz; ++i) {
        printf("%02x ", p[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well shoot me down! ;-)

Comment: This in no way answers the question actually asked.

Comment: yes but there is another one which doesn't do any formatting and begins with \xHH

Comment: @Vicky: There seems to be a fine line these days between "can you help me do something" and "can you do something for me".  I prefer pointing in the right direction, not spoon feeding

Comment: @Craig, I think you missed the point of the question entirely. The OP knows about the %x format specifier but didn't understand how to get only one byte of the multi-byte data type.

Comment: thanks all of you.I preferred to hear more about formatting and correct myself if my definition of d formatter in C which i have listed with numbers 1 & 2 corresponds exactly to your definitions.Also as i mentioned in reply to mbratch, i wanted to see my memory bytes the same as a debugger does. Paul-R gave me the hint that I'm not able to unless i use a pointer.