# formatter size in printf()

Tags: c, printf

Regarding question [Why do I have to specify data type each time in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203636/why-do-i-have-to-specify-data-type-each-time-in-c/18203775#18203775) and my earlier question [how to read memory bytes one by one in hex(so without any format) with printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273136/how-to-read-memory-bytes-one-by-one-in-hexso-without-any-format-with-printf)

Is it possible to clarify the below question for me?

```
int32_t a[3]={21,3,1000031}; 
char* p1=&a[0]; /* char is 1-bye and &a[0] is 0x0004 for example */

printf("p1 in hex=%x\n",*p1); /* 4 bytes starting from word-aligned address p1 */
printf("(p1+3)=%d",(p1+3));   /* 4 bytes starting from a NON word-aligned address?* line 2 printf */
printf("p1+3=%p",p1+3) /* line 3 print*/
```

%x and %d **ALWAYS** tell printf to use int format which in my pc is a 4-byte? am i right?

(p1+3) is a non-word aligned address Ox004+3=**0x007**,so what does printf() show in this case?in another way, which bytes are concerned by line 2 printf?

also, %p formatter(void *) does it need 1 byte to read(because of char)or since we talk about pointers and they always take 4 bytes(one-word)?

to sum up my questions, %d %x %p,.. do they read a constant size(depending on pc) from memory or it depends on what are the size of their corresponding arguments?

Comment: `printf("%d", sizeof(int));` will tell you how many bytes an `int` is on your system.

Comment: You should use `%zu` to print a `size_t`, not `%d`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your code shows clearly what you want to ask, but to answer your sum-up question:

> %d %x %p,.. do they read a constant size(depending on pc) from memory or it depends on what are the size of their corresponding arguments?

They read the size depends on the size of specific type on the machine. For example, for a 32-bit machine, `%d` will read 4 bytes, because it assumes the variable is an `int`.

I think this piece of code shows the general idea:

```
int a = 1089;
printf("%c\n", a);  // prints "A" on a little-endian machine
printf("%d\n", a);  // prints "1089"
```

Comment: my code doesn't show anything. i was just playing with pointers and printf().in your above code, I think that second argument of printf() just gives this function, the first byte address of a variable. then the first argument of printf() shows how many bytes to read from memory starting from that address.

Comment: On big-endian machines (SPARC, PPC), your `%c` example will print a null byte, not `A`.  On little-endian machines, it'll work OK.

Comment: @YuHao could you please  tell me what would be the output of this::  printf("(p1+3)=%d",*(p1+3)); //nonword-align                         also in First 1-,when you say that the code prints whatever *p is as hex,it seems to me that printf doesn't know how many bytes constitute *p, it will look at its first argument which is %x, so it will take 4 bytes.(it doesn't look at int32_t for deciding 4 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

Variadic parameters, just like all other parameter passing in C, is pass-by-value only.  There's no address of anything going on in your case.  In some cases you're printing the *value* of a pointer variable, though.  I'll try to explain in order:

1. First:

   ```
   printf("p1 in hex=%x\n",*p1);
   ```

   Prints whatever `*p1` is as a hex number.  That's either `15` or `0`, depending on whether you have  a little- or big-endian machine, respectively.
2. Next:

   ```
   printf("(p1+3)=%d",(p1+3));
   ```

   Will try to print whatever `p1 + 3` is as a decimal number.  Since `p1` is a pointer, that's not really a sane thing to do, and technically this statement causes undefined behaviour.  You should be using `%p` to print a pointer.  Assuming pointers and `int` are the same size on your machine, you'll probably get some number, but probably not a really meaningful one.
3. Last:

   ```
   printf("p1+3=%p",p1+3)
   ```

   `%p` prints a pointer type, so this line is correct.  You'll (probably) get the same value as in #2, except in hexadecimal format.  That's all machine/implementation-specific, though.

As to your other questions:

> `%x` and `%d` ALWAYS tell printf to use int format which in my pc is a 4-byte? am i right?

`%x` is for `unsigned int` and `%d` is for `int`.  The `%x` will give you hexadecimal output, and the `%d` decimal output.  If `int` is a four-byte type on your machine, they'll both print the corresponding 4 bytes-worth of arguments that you passed.

> `(p1+3)` is a non-word aligned address Ox004+3=0x007,so what does printf() show in this case?in another way, which bytes are concerned by line 2 printf?

Since you're printing the pointer value itself, the alignment is meaningless.  You shouldn't be using `%d` to do it though (as mentioned above).  The address in question is probably not `7`, either... I'm not really sure where you got that from.

> also, `%p` formatter(`void *`) does it need 1 byte to read(because of char)or since we talk about pointers and they always take 4 bytes(one-word)?

`%p` must be paired with a `void *` argument, as you say.  It will will print the appropriate size for the pointer type on your machine (sounds like 4 bytes in your case).

> to sum up my questions, `%d` `%x` `%p`,.. do they read a constant size(depending on pc) from memory or it depends on what are the size of their corresponding arguments?

They don't necessarily read *anything* from memory - that depends on how your ABI works and what the calling convention is for variadic functions your machine.  You have to match types between the format specifiers and the corresponding variables, or else you'll cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: could you please  tell me what would be the output of this::  printf("(p1+3)=%d",*(p1+3)); //non word-align

Comment: do you have any idea about what is printed in the case of:  printf("(p1+3)=%d",*(p1+3)); //non word-align

Comment: That depends on if your machine is little endian or big endian and on how bit `char` is.  Either `0` or `21`, I guess.